# Sharepoint 2010 central administration empty page displaying after installation of ADDS on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express, domaincontroller

I have installed SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2. To make server as Domain Controller and to install Active Directory i have installed ADDS using dcpromo.exe command. I have installed ADDS successfully but SharePoint 2010 Central Administration stopped working. Initially it was giving error "Service Unavailable 503 ERROR" and "Configuration data not found". I have resolved this error by SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard and connected to old config database. Now site is opening but empty page displaying. Please any suggestion or solution to fix this issue? Thanks

Here are few logs that i collected from event log -

Failure trying to synch web application a930387b-e899-460c-85ed-3f3b5100a6b0, ContentDB 7bba3ca6-d2f3-4577-a6c9-627fdb0bdbb7  Exception message was Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

Comment: i tried following link but no success - http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/06/getting-blank-page-instead-of-central.html

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to check sharepoint logs and windows logs for that particular moment when you are trying to access CA. This should give you more information on what is happening and maybe you can provide this to us as for now it is lack of information.